# Pedestrian arrival rate of 5 per h only 3 showing for 1 h during the simulation. Any reason why?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent

I'm trying to simulate a pedestrian flow in the entrance of an hospital.

We are installing check-in platforms and I want to know how many platforms we should get according to the patient flow.

I'm using Anylogic personal learning edition and when I put an arrival rate of 5 per hour during the simulation only 3 appears.

I'm trying to understand how anylogic works and distribute the pedestrians according to the rate we put.

For the personnal learning edition 1h equal 1min in real.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6iTT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

if you choose rate=5, the pedSource block will generate pedestrians with an exponentially distributed interarrival time with mean = 1/rate = 1/5.

Which means that the average of arrivals on the long term will be 5, but you won't get 5 every hour since it's a stochastic variable.

If you change the seed, you will have different arrivals... click on Simulation: Main and you can change the seed or use a random seed:
[image: Random Seed]

Now if you really want exactly 5 per hour in a deterministic way, you need to change the arrival from rate to inject function:

[image: inject function]

Then you can create an event that runs cyclically 5 times per hour.. or 1 time every 12 minutes:

and you do `pedSource.inject(1);`